# Save Array with AJAX Request - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to update all records of a card model simultaneously. I'm getting the data for each card with a map function, then sending the data with and AJAX request.

```
var cards = ui.item.parent('.js-CardsContainer .js-CardContainer').map(function() {
    return {
        list_id: $(this).closest('.js-List').data('id'),
        order: $(this).index
    }
}).get();

$.ajax({
    url: "/cards/",
    type: "PATCH",
    data: { cards: cards },
    success: function(resp){
    }
});
```

I don't know how to handle this data with rails though. Which action in my cards controller do I put the logic in? And what should that logic look like?

I imagine I need something like this...

```
def index
    cards.each(&:save!)
end
```

Obviously that is incorrect though. Can anyone help?

Here is the log output when the data is sent:

```
Started PATCH "/cards/" for ::1 at 2017-01-06 21:57:05 +0000
```

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/cards"):

actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in`call_app'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`catch'
web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in`call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in`call'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in`process_client'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in`block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb
  Rendering /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb
  Rendered /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/colmtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (30.8ms)

Comment: Are you creating new `Card` records, or updating existing ones?

Comment: Updating existing ones.

Comment: How does your params collection look like? Can you paste the log output?

Comment: I updated the question with my cards controller, including the params section

Comment: But I wanted to see the actual request parameters sent from the JS, just like they appear in your log output and how they hit the controller.

Comment: I'm not sure, in the console it says "Array[0]" length: 0. I guess that means there's something wrong with my Javascript?

Comment: Oh, I just realised what you meant, sorry. I've updated the question with the log now.